Can't get tryCatch to work using foreeach in R
The tryCatch with error and warnings handling worked fine when I used a simple serial function but when I try to use foreach instead to do it in parallel, it doesn't work for some reason.
It just doesn't write anything.
The foreach function seems to output some warning (Warning: number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)) but it doesn't hint me where it occurs, then strangely R hangs and I have to restart it.
Does this not work when using foreeach? very thankful for all help I can get! I have googled and asked copilot and chatgpt with no success:/
Here is my code:
run_model_parallel <- function(data, dep_var, snps, name) {
 # Print current variable and test
 message("Variable: ", dep_var, " test: ", name)
 
 # Start row counter on row 1
 counter <- 1
 
 cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
 
 
 # Initialize parallel backend
 registerDoSNOW(cl)
 
 # Initialize progress bar
 pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(snps), style = 3)
 progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
 opts <- list(progress = progress)
 
 # Loop through all SNPs in parallel
 result_list <- foreach(
           i = snps,
           .combine = rbind,
           .packages = c("dplyr", "geepack"),
           .export = c("name", "pb", "progress"),
           .options.snow = opts
           ) %dopar% {
                
               
                
                # Define the formula to be used in the model
                formula <- as.formula(paste(
                     dep_var,
                     " ~ AGE + AGE.2 + SEX + BMI + ",
                     i,
                     sep = ""))
                
                
                
                # hold data temporary and remove NA's
                df_temp <- na.omit(data %>%
                                        dplyr::select(
                                             PAT,
                                             !!sym(dep_var),
                                             AGE,
                                             AGE.2,
                                             SEX,
                                             BMI,
                                             all_of(i))) %>%
                     
                     # set major/ref allele (2) to be the model reference                                 condition when running geese()                            
                     mutate(!!sym(i) := factor(!!sym(i), levels = c(2, 1)))
                     
           # Run model if rows are >= 10
           # and smallest groups of 0 or 1 should be at least 3
           if (nrow(df_temp) >= 10 &&
               min(sum(df_temp[, i] == 1), sum(df_temp[, i] == 2)) >= 3) {
                
                
                # Run generalized estimating equation
                tryCatch({
                     model <- geese(
                          formula = formula,
                          data = df_temp,
                          id = PAT,
                          corstr = "exchangeable",
                          family = binomial(link = "logit")
                          )
                     
                     # Store estimate, se and p-value
                     # length(df_temp)-1 is used to extract the correct row                             depending on the number of independent variables used
                     temp <- signif(summary(model)$mean[length(df_temp)-1, c(1, 2, 4)],
                                    digits = 7)
                     # Set column names
                     names(temp) <- c(paste0(name, "_estimate"),
                                      paste0(name, "_se"),
                                      paste0(name, "_p_value"))
                     
                     counter <- counter + 1
                },
                
                # Error handling
                error = function(e) {
                     cat(
                          "Error in df: ",
                          name,
                          ", counter: ",
                          counter,
                          ", SNP: ",
                          i,
                          ", dependent variable: ",
                          dep_var,
                          "\n"
                     )
                     cat("Error message: ",
                         conditionMessage(e),
                         "\n")
                     print(df_temp)
                },
                
                # Warning handling
                warning = function(w) {
                     cat(
                          "Warning in df: ",
                          name,
                          ", counter: ",
                          counter,
                          ", SNP: ",
                          i,
                          ", dependent variable: ",
                          dep_var,
                          "\n"
                     )
                     cat("Warning message: ",
                         conditionMessage(w),
                         "\n")
                     print(paste("df_temp: ", df_temp))
                })
                
           } else {
                
           # Add NA to results if filtered out from model
           temp <- rep(NA, 3)
           
           names(temp) <- c(paste0(name, "_estimate"),
                            paste0(name, "_se"),
                            paste0(name, "_p_value"))
           }
           
           # Add additional columns
           temp <- c(
                temp, 
                Chr = as.numeric(gsub("^X(\\d+)\\.(\\d+.*)$", "\\1", i)),
                Position = as.numeric(gsub("^X(\\d+)\\.(\\d+.*)$", "\\2", i)),
                Clusters = length(unique(df_temp[[1]])),
                Ref = sum(df_temp[[i]] == 2),
                Alt = sum(df_temp[[i]] == 1),
                Ratio = signif(sum(df_temp[[i]] == 1) / sum(df_temp[[i]] == 2), digits = 7)
                )
           
           # Update progress bar
           #pb$tick()
           
           # Return all info for the SNP being run
           return(temp)
      }
 # Close progressbar
 close(pb)
 
 # Close the cluster when finished
 stopCluster(cl)
 
 result_df <- do.call(rbind, result_list)
 
 result_df <- result_list %>% as.data.frame() %>%
      relocate(Chr, Position, .before = 1) %>%
      mutate(Ratio = ifelse(Ratio == 0 | is.na(Ratio) | Ratio == Inf, 
                            NA,
                            Ratio))
 
 rownames(result_df) <- NULL
 colnames(result_df) <- c("Chr",
                          "Position",
                          paste0(name, "_estimate"),
                          paste0(name, "_se"),
                          paste0(name, "_p_value"),
                          paste0("nr_of_clusters_PAT_", name),
                          paste0("Ref_", name),
                          paste0("Alt_",name),
                          paste0("Alt/Ref_ratio_", name)
                          )
 result_df <- result_df %>%
      unnest(cols = c("Chr",
                      "Position",
                      paste0(name, "_estimate"),
                      paste0(name, "_se"),
                      paste0(name, "_p_value"),
                      paste0("nr_of_clusters_PAT_", name), 
                      paste0("Ref_", name),
                      paste0("Alt_",name),
                      paste0("Alt/Ref_ratio_", name)
                      ))

 
 return(result_df)

}

You cannot use global variables (such as your counter) in parallel computing. The parallel workers cannot modify objects outside their scope.

ah ofc!:D that just accidentally followed when I configured my serial function to the parallel.
but besides that, the tryCatch, error and warning still doesn't work:(

You cannot use print and cat in parallel processing. The output streams don't go to the main R session.

Also, treat tryCatch like a function (because it is one). The error and warning handlers should provide alternative return values for that function. You should assign the return value (probably to temp?).

aha I see, what can I use of print or cat doesnt work?
I'm not sure I understand what you mean wirh your last answer? sorry for being obtuse:)

Generally, I recommend you set up tryCatch like this:
result <- tryCatch({
  DF <- someFunction(someInput)
  #I assume someFunction returns a data.frame with two columns V1 and V2

  DF$diagnostics <- ""
  DF
  }, error = function(e) {
    DF <- data.frame(V1 = NA,
                     V2 = NA,
                     diagnostics = conditionMessage(e))
    DF
    }
  )

The iterations of your foreach loop should return result (possibly further processed).
If this doesn't help, provide a minimal reproducible example.
